# I found this deck of cards and have no clue what it is called or how it is played

Tags: identify-this-game

Example of card names: The Magil, Sirens of Aphron, Tristes Unum, Cerga Mobster etc.

I have 64 cards. All 64 cards are different. Top left of the Cerga Mobster card is written 14 FrP - 12 Gui - 9 Lck as do other cards but with different amounts. See attached pictures.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post a link to any pictures of the cards?

Comment: If you can't post pictures - how many cards in the pack?  Are there obvious "suits"? Can you give more description?

Comment: Wow, no google hits for any of those card names, interesting!

Comment: I thought they might be movie related, so I searched for the quotes in the text boxes. Nothing there, either.

Comment: I don't intend judgement, but the design quality looks kinda low.  Totally guessing, but to me, looks like somebody's prototype game.

Comment: To add to Radhil's note, the card on the right uses a [random image from the Internet](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/a5/15/fd/a515fdef5150bb250dcd7fd66a60c72d.jpg) that's apparently from a Renaissance fair. These cards were almost certainly never published publicly.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. I will not give up on this. Tomorrow I will go downtown and inquire at a Novelty store.

Comment: what is on the backside?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea at all what these are, but based on the complete lack of google entries, I am guessing they are homemade.

Regarding the three stats 'FrP', 'Gui', and 'Lck'.  I'm not sure what FrP is, but maybe the others are Guile and Luck?  Perhaps these are for some role playing game with those three character statistics?

My guess is that these were printed by someone for a campaign in some role playing game, maybe even a homebrew RPG.